# How can I easily place multiple powershell windows on login?

Tags: script, powershell

I like to have a 2x2 grid of powershell windows open on my alternate monitor, but I'd prefer not to have to open and resize each one by hand.  I can set the window size (through `(Get-Host).UI.RawUI.WindowSize`), but it appears that `(Get-Host).UI.RawUI.WindowPosition` is actually the scroll position within the buffer.

Does anyone know of any way to do this through PS scripting, or, failing that, through the Windows Scripting Host?

Comment: You might need to use `Add-Type` to access some Windows API functions via C# to achieve that.

Comment: If you want a non-code solution, in Vista and 7 you can right-click on the taskbar and choose 'show windows side by side'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asking the question prompted me to change my Google query string, and I've stumbled upon the correct way to do this.

First, download [WASP](http://wasp.codeplex.com/).  Make sure `Import-Module Wasp` is in your profile.

Then I created this script (appropriate for a pair of 1920x1200 monitors, with the "main" monitor being on the right):

```
#
# the pause is necessary to make sure the powershell consoles have
# had time to create their windows before attempting to move them
start (which powershell)
$g0x1 = start (which powershell) -PassThru
$g1x1 = start (which powershell) -PassThru

pause 2

set-windowposition -window ((get-process -id $g0x1.id).MainWindowHandle) -left -1168 -top 0 -height 598
set-windowposition -window ((get-process -id $g1x1.id).MainWindowHandle) -left -1168 -top 600 -height 598
```

The `pause` function is simply:

```
function pause
{
   param($p)
   wait-event -timeout $p
}
```

Comment: Even better, I now use ConEmu, which has nice splitter functionality built in.